# AOSP Build failed: ninja failed with: exit status 1

Tags: android, android-source, ninja

My AOSP (PixelExperience) build fails with the error message below and I got no idea how to fix it.
Anyone here that got the knowlegde to provide me a possible fix?

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lukas/disk/pixelExperience/pixelExperience/out/target/product/cepheus/obj/KERNEL_OBJ'
make: Leaving directory '/home/lukas/disk/pixelExperience/pixelExperience/kernel/xiaomi/cepheus'
make: Entering directory '/home/lukas/disk/pixelExperience/pixelExperience/kernel/xiaomi/cepheus'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lukas/disk/pixelExperience/pixelExperience/out/target/product/cepheus/obj/KERNEL_OBJ'
  GEN     ./Makefile
scripts/kconfig/conf  --savedefconfig=defconfig Kconfig
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lukas/disk/pixelExperience/pixelExperience/out/target/product/cepheus/obj/KERNEL_OBJ'
make: Leaving directory '/home/lukas/disk/pixelExperience/pixelExperience/kernel/xiaomi/cepheus'
17:39:17 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

Comment: Could you tell us if you resolved your error / add more lines? I have similar finishing output so maybe we've got the same problem (ccache: Failed to read from file stream)

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment yet, I'll leave it here.

Your error is not in the lines you shared. Share a more complete log, with [katb.in](https://katb.in) or [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) for example, otherwise there is nothing we can do.

Comment: I have similar finishing output so I suppose it's `ccache: Failed to read from file stream`, do you know what can be the cause?